# Phonegap - SpeechRecognition is not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

I am adding the below SpeechRecognition plugin in my phonegap hybrid project -
https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin

But, the speech recognition is not working. When emulating it on chrome, I am getting javascript error - "**Uncaught ReferenceError: SpeechRecognition is not defined**"

I have already done "**phonegap build**" and "**phonegap prepare**"

Also, I read somewhere that the Speech Recognition code needs to be in a deviceready event callback. I also tried that but didn't work. Then realised that mine is a multi-page application and deviceready works only on the first page when phonegap is loaded. Whereas I am using this Speech Recognition API on a different page.

Basically I am making a multi-page (not single html using multiple page tag) hybrid application and want to use the SpeechRecognition API.

Would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Anybody please help. Really stuck here :(

Comment: You have to use it on the page where cordova.js is linked and after device ready event is fired. If you have a multi page app you have to link cordova.js in all of them and wait for device ready on each of them. And you can't test on Chrome, the plugin only works on iOS and Android as an app, not on browsers

Comment: Thanks @jcesarmobile for your solution.
But, how do I link cordova.js to other html pages which are in another folders like html/voice/voice.html.
I tried linking like this -
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../cordova.js"></script>
but then cordova.js throws error because it cannot find config.xml now where cordova.js uses absolute path.

Comment: Then you should learn about single page applications

Comment: @jcesarmobile, it is a really big application with many pages. Is it feasible or advisable to be done as a single page application ? It will have to load so many DOM elements of all the pages say like around 40 pages.

Comment: You can load just the page you are going to navigate to using an XHR call, and then once you navigate back you can destroy what you loaded. If you can't do it, at least put the void.html in the root of your project instead of putting it in html/voice/